# "He was a father to someone." OR "He was a father of someone."

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions, phrase-meaning

This is from the BBC [Mr. Stanton](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-66121634)

**Mr Stanton was a father to a four-year-old daughter and a sports fan.**

As I read, **"to be a father to someone"** drew my attention. I wondered why **"...father of...."** instead of **"...father to..."?**

I made some research about differences in meaning between the two, and I learned from some language forums that **"father of"** might indicate **"biological father"** while "**father to"** might indicate **"being like a father".**

I am not sure whether the difference is so distinct among native speakers.

If yes, why does the **"BBC"** use **"father to"**?

Comment: *I learned that "father of" indicates "biological father" while "father to" means "being like a father"* - where did you find this?  As a native speaker, this doesn't seem like a distinction I would make.

Comment: @stangdon, It is mostly forums: For example: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/230011/father-to-vs-father-of#:~:text=Both%20are%20correct%2C%20grammatically%20as,(not%20of%20me).%22 And here is another one: https://www.quora.com/Which-one-is-grammatically-correct-I-am-a-father-to-him-or-I-am-a-father-of-him

Comment: @stangdon  When referring someone who is not a father, but is like a father, only "of" is used: "*He's like a father **to** her*"; incorrect: "*He's like a father **of** hers.*"

Comment: @gotube It looks like you meant to write, 'only **"to"** is used' for someone who is *like* a father.

Comment: @gotube Thanks for explaining.  I think the difference you see in those forum posts has more to do with the difference between "He is X of Y" and "He is X to me" in general than with anything to do specifically with being a father.   For example, "He is a friend *to* her" is more natural than "of her", but neither has anything to do with biology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preposition ***to*** is and always was perfectly valid in such contexts, and it's *starting* to be used more often lately. But [mostly we still prefer ***of...***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mother%20of%20two%2Cmother%20to%20two&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

[image]

---

OP's idea that the choice of preposition reflects *actual **biological** parenthood* as opposed to *[adopting a child and] acting in the **role** of* a parent is completely spurious. Except it's more idiomatic to say *John is **the** father **of** Jane* than *John is father **to** Jane* for true parenthood, and it's always *John is **like a** father **to** Jack* for figurative / adoption contexts. It's the idiomatically established *construction* that dictates the preposition.

Comment: I could say that someone was like a father to me, but not that he was like a father of me (or of mine).

Comment: Syntactically, there's no reason why you couldn't use ***of*** after ***like a father***. It's just a matter of what's become idiomatically established. I think we tend to use *X **to** Y* when ***X*** is the more "important" component, but I wouldn't like to put money on it either way.

Comment: They say it's a wise man who knows who his father is. 'He was like a father of mine' sounds  distinctly odd from a biological point of view (how many fathers does a fellow need?). Nobody says 'that's a coat of me', or am I being obtuse?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, Nobody says 'that's a coat of me'. Yes, that is right but interestingly, everybody says "a picture of me" instead of "my picture".

Comment: I say 'my picture' about an image in which I appear, or 'his photo/picture/portrait' about one somebody else appears in. _The cat doesn't look anything like its picture_ is something I might very well say. Probably to do with being born in 1837, I daresay.